# Python multiprocessing restart after join

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using python multiprocessing Process. Why can't I start or restart a process after it exits and I do a join. The process is gone, but in the instantiated class _popen is not set to None after the process dies and I do a join. If I try and start again it tells me I can't start a process twice.

Comment: Did you try doing `Process.is_alive()` to see if its alive?

Answer (score 2):

From the Python multiprocessing documentation.

> start()
>
> Start the process’s activity.
>
> This must be called at most once per process object. It arranges for the object’s run() method to be invoked in a separate process.

A Process object can be run only once. If you need to re-run the same routine (the target parameter) you must instantiate a new Process object.

This is due to the fact that Process objects are encapsulating unique OS instances.

Tip: do not play with the internals of Python Thread and Process objects, you might get seriously hurt. 
The _popen attribute you're seeing is a sentinel the Process object uses to understand when the child OS process is gone. It's literally a pipe and it's used to block the join() call until the process does not terminate.

Answer (score -2):

From your question we can just guess, what you're talking about. Are you using `subprocess`? How do you start your process? By invoking `call()` or `Popen()`?

In case I guessed right:

Just keep your `args` list from your `subprocess` call and restart your process by calling that command again. The instance of your subprocess (e.g. a `Popen` instance) represents a running process (with **one** PID) rather than an abstract application which can be run multiple time.

e.g.:

```
args = ['python', 'myscript.py']
p = Popen(args)
p.wait()
p = Popen(args)
...
```

Comment: OP is probably using the `multiprocessing` library, not `subprocess`.